# How to install Playstore on a device on which it is not already installed?

Tags: google-play-store

I bought a VivoY13 phone from Chinese Dealer.  But Google playstore is not pre-installed.

And when you try to install it shows errors.

Does anyone have solutions or faced  similar situation?

Comment: What errors are shown? Please [edit] to describe them and add a screenshot if possible. Also see [similar questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-play-store%5D+chinese) with solutions that may work for you

Comment: @beeshyams the question is rather "how did you install it". First, it needs the GSF (Google Services Framework) – and second, it needs to be a system app. // **Franklin:** as a hint, many of our tags have useful wikis attached. If you e.g. take a look at the [google-play-store tag-wiki](/tags/google-play-store/info), it would lead you to [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](/q/27808/16575). Though I'm happy to have a device without that Google stuff; runs much smoother. And I use F-Droid instead, much safer :)

Comment: I'm Really Thankful For Your Quick Response.....

Comment: But In Respect To My Question On How To Install Playstore Google Services On VivoY13 Android Phone Which Your Answer Is Apparently On How To Install Playstore Services Not Specifying The Steps And Apps Needed To Run It On The Android Version Type Device.

Comment: @FranklinEmissary Doesn't the question I've linked explain that? Why should there be a separate explanation for each of the thousands of Android devices existing? You only need to flash the GApps package matching you *Android version* – regardless of the device. Also see our [google-apps tag-wiki](/tags/google-apps/info) for alternative sources of GApps. AFAIK, OpenGApps should be the best choice.

Comment: How Do I Download The GApp Then, because I Find Difficult Downloading With The Phone.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are a victim of purchasing a tampered device.

**Why do scammers and hackers sell tampered device's ?**

- Copying sensitive data ( bank details )
- Hacking user's information
- Stealing passwords and other security data

---

**How do they steal data ?**

- The seller purchases a new device, then gains root access and installs hack software on the device.    ( malware, spyware etc... ) and sells it on eBay and other sites.

**Is this a serious issue ?**
YES.  You should NEVER use a device with hacked firmware for anything... it could be logging everything you do...

- text messages
- internet access
- call logs and recordings
- everything your device has access to

---

**What can i do to remove the hacks**

- Download an OFFICIAL stock ROM ( Firmware )
  [YOUR DEVICE FIRMWARES - NeedRom.com](https://www.needrom.com/category/vivo/y13l/)
- Download the Latest SP Flash Tool ( most MTK china phones use SP Flash Tool)
- Install your STOCK OFFICIAL firmware following the guide on needrom.com

**Why would Google Services be missing ?**
Usually this is to comply with Copyright laws, the seller isn't legally aloud to sell you proprietary software on a modified system.

Also, Google Play Protect will alert the user of any suspicious applications on the device, and also check for ( Certified Device )

**Certified Device !!!**
After installing your OFFICIAL STOCK Firmware, you can check the integrity of the system using the built-in recovery, just boot into recovery and do a system integrity check.... After all is OK, boot the device and open Googles Play Store,   Navigate to settings and scroll to the bottom, at the bottom of the settings screen in the Play Store, it'll say if your on a Certified Device or not...

If it Say's certified device, and you have all OK in system integrity check, your good to go and all services like Android Pay will be accessible.

The flashing instructions are usually basic, but be careful NOT to use Firmware Upgrade... Only Ever Download, in SP Flash Tool.

Good Luck, I've had many tampered with devices from online purchases, but all are fixable :)
Especially Chinese MTK models.

Answer (score 0):

Before you try anything too radical, you can try to sideload Google Play store without flashing. First, [find out the android version you are running](https://www.howtogeek.com/230737/how-to-find-out-which-version-of-android-you-have/), for example, 4.4, 6.0, and so on. Then go to [the apk mirror site](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/) to download a play store apk (which is equivalent to a exe installer on a computer) for your version. BEWARE, do not go around and use many other 3rd party app websites, as many of them are very scammy. To "sideload" an app, follow [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/313433/how-to-sideload-apps-on-android/) guide.

Comment: This is seriously bad advice...

Comment: You will still have an infected device !!!! It's utterly stupid.... he did not remove the play store ... The Seller Did !!!! .... Don't be gullible because you aren't confident in your ability.

Comment: If you are worried about Damage's ... here's a guide to do a complete backup first  https://youtu.be/e2_U68EGSlY